# Styling php code for showing on my website

Tags: php, parsing

I want to show pieces of user inputted PHP code on my website. My problem is the styling of this code, is there a project which can parse the PHP code (and style it) for me or do i have to create a PHP parser/styler myself? (I have searched the web but i can't find what I'm looking for)

My website is written in PHP, with the Yii framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A built-in start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Comment: can't find ? try to google "php code source highlighter", this will yield plenty of results.

Comment: I'm not as good with English, i only found tutorials on how to make a website, probably used the wrong words to search...

Comment: The highlighter is exactly what i need, Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `highlight_string()` function

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [highlight-string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) method.

For parsing PHP you could use the [Tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.tokenizer.php).

Answer (score -1):

if you need code parser check this ext.:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiidecoda/

I it's help